# to call js method from a js file during asynchronus postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a javascript method on a JS file and I want to call that method after asynchronous post back on the click event of a link button.So I have written that code in the pageLoad function in the js file.The method is calling fine after asynchronous post back,when I am writing the javascript code on the aspx page itself,but the code is not running when it is written in the js file .One more problem is I am using an html control instead of an ASP control.So it does not have any asynchronous post back trigger.But I need to call the js method after asynchronous post back on the click event of the link button, from the js file itself.So how to fix it.

below is the sample code

```
 <input type="button" id="btnLnkMore" value="More..." class="moreLink" />
```

**Javascript code in the js file:**

```
function pageLoad() {
    debugger;
    $("#btnLnkMore").click(function (e) {

//code

    });
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but isn't pageLoad() an ASP function and not JavaScript? You might be looking for something like window.onload()

Comment: @armadadrive `pageLoad()` is an event in MS AJAX library, client-side.